# ANGULAR CRUD httpclient error in my service.spec.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to create the user service and importing httpclient, when i did that i recieved an error in my service.spec.ts on 'new UserService' saying 'An argument for 'httpClient' was not provided' what should i do????

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule,
  ],
  providers: [HttpClientModule,],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn :'root'})
export class UserService {
    readonly API_URL ='http://localhost:8080/api/user';

    constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient){}
    addUser(user : any){
        return this.httpClient.post('${this.API_URL}/adduser', user)
    }
    updateUser(user: any){
        return this.httpClient.put('${this.API_URL}/updateuser', user)
    }
    deleteUser(idUser: any){
        return this.httpClient.delete('${this.API_URL}/deleteuser/${idUser}')
    }
    getAllUsers(){
        return this.httpClient.get('${this.API_URL}/allusers')
    }
}
```

```
import { UserService } from './user-service';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
describe('UserService', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    expect(new UserService()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: `new UserService()` indeed provides no argument to be the `httpClient` - where did you _expect_ it to come from? You're certainly not using Angular's DI, maybe read the testing guidance: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you are testing service and the constructor has httpClient, you need to configure the HttpClient/HttpClientTestingModule in beforeEach

```
import { HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { UserService } from './user-service';

describe('UserService', () => {
   let userService : UserService;

 beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
  service=TestBed.inject(userService); })
 })

   it('should create an instance', () => {
   expect(service()).toBeTruthy();
  });
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a type of HttpClient as it is a dependency in your service.
This will look something like below code in your spec.ts file.

```
describe('UserService', () => {
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    expect(new UserService(httpClient)).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: Your httpClient is not being assigned to anything, this would still fail. In these cases it is recommended to mock the httpClient service, since we don't want to make the actual http calls. Here's an example https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#testing-http-services